# How to debugg Background assets in simulator in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, background-assets-framework

Is there any way to simulate background assets in xcode simulators?

I tried in actual device using `xcrun backgroundassets-debug` but the attached process removed automatically when I trigger the app update event.I'm using xcode 15 RC build